# Set custom colors for two plots in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following code for some pie charts:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen']
labels2 = ['Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500]
values2 = [ 1053, 500]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}]])


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels, values= values, name=""),
              1, 1)


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels2, values= values, name=""),
              1, 2)
fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name")

title = "PERCENTAGE OF SHOTS ON YOUR TEAM"


fig.update_layout(
    title_text=title,
    # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
    annotations=[dict(text='', x=0.18, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False),
                 dict(text='', x=0.82, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False)])

fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label')
fig.show()
```

It generates the following image:

[image]

Overall the plot is fine, but I need to specify the colors, e.g.

```
colors = [ '#00c600', '#66b3ff',"#1f77b4",'#d62728']
```

But it I add it as:

```
fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name",marker=dict(colors=colors))
```

The new code is:

```
labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen']
labels2 = ['Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500]
values2 = [ 1053, 500]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}]])


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels, values= values, name=""),
              1, 1)


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels2, values= values, name=""),
              1, 2)


fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name",marker=dict(colors=colors))


title = "PERCENTAGE OF SHOTS ON YOUR TEAM"


fig.update_layout(
    title_text=title,
    # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
    annotations=[dict(text='', x=0.18, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False),
                 dict(text='', x=0.82, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False)])

fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label')
fig.show()
```

The problem is that now it is using only 2 colors and I need to have one color for each value:

[image]

Comment: you know the solution as well

Comment: @DivyesshMaheshwari No, becuase that way is not easy to read, I not able to set colors for each item so I have 4 colors and it is easier to read.

Comment: You know how to set colors so make two more that will take much lesser time than getting answers

Comment: if you want to support I can write same in answer and you can upvote, Or if you need I can find colors for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column arguments in the update_traces method, this will work on figures with subplots.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

#colors = [ '#00c600', '#66b3ff',"#1f77b4",'#d62728']
colors2 = [ "#1f77b4",'#d62728']
colors3 = [ '#00c600', '#66b3ff']


labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen']
labels2 = ['Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500]
values2 = [ 1053, 500]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}]])


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels, values= values, name=""),
              1, 1)


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels2, values= values, name=""),
              1, 2)

fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name",marker=dict(colors=colors2),col=0)
fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo="label+percent+name",marker=dict(colors=colors3),col=1)



title = "PERCENTAGE OF SHOTS ON YOUR TEAM"


fig.update_layout(
    title_text=title,
    # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
    annotations=[dict(text='', x=0.18, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False),
                 dict(text='', x=0.82, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False)])

fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label')
fig.show()
```

The update_traces has a col/row parameter, there is also a selector parameter:

```
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(color="RoyalBlue"),
                  col=2)
```

References:

- https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/
- https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.update_traces